# Cookie passing to another url

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, http, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies

My solution has 2 projects: `MyApp.WebApi` and `MyApp.Web`.

The `MyApp.WebApi` contains all the `ApiController`s to return required `Json` data. It also has `AccountController.Login` action which should return the `TokenId`, also  automatically set the `TokrnId` in the cookies.

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Login(string username, string password)
{
    var principal = // Some code to get the principal
    var tokenId = principal.TicketId;
    var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("TokenId", tokenId)
    { 
        Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1),
        Domain = this.Request.RequestUri.Host, Path = "/" 
    };

    resp.Headers.AddCookies(new[] { cookie });
    resp.Content = new StringContent(tokenId);
    return resp;
}
```

It work fine using the browser.
But when I use it within `MyApp.Web` the `$.getJSON` requests don't send the requests with the `TokenId` cookie.

```
$.getJSON(serviceAddress)
    .done(function (result, status) {
        // Do some logic
    })
    .fail(function (result, status) {
        logger.logError(result);

    });
```

**Question1.** How could I make `HttpRequest`s via `MyApp.Web` send the cookies?

**Question2.** I want my Login method to return `string` instead of `HttpResponseMessage`. but in that case I don't know how to set the cookies as I have not access to the returning response directly(eg. `resp`)